# Does armor/encumbrance affect all movement types or just foot speed?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, movement, flight, encumbrance

Does wearing armor/encumbrance reduce all types of movement speeds or only your land speed?

The [armor table](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/armor) only lists for 20 & 30 speeds.
The table located in carrying capacity for [armor and encumbrance for other base speeds](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/alignment-description/carrying-capacity#TOC-Table-Encumbrance-Effects) would seem to indicate otherwise, as it lists from 5 to 120 speed.

The table says for all base speeds, so is that referring to all movement types (fly, burrow, swim, ...) as a base speed or just all land speeds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes (for your own) and no (for mounts & devices):

Armor changes the movement speed of the one wearing the armor, as soon as it does encumber at all. So on this case, it is **yes**, you get a reduced movement speed on all of **your** movement ratings unless you have a feat that spares you of those.

However, keep in mind several classes have a good chance to be mounted on a being that can have other movements while in heavy armor (like a Chevalier or Paladin on a Pegasus or a Druid on a Roc). Unless the ride wears a fitted armor (barding), it will move with its own movement speed, only accounting you if you get too heavy. So **no** you don't account your armor on **your mount's** movement rating (but keep in mind it adds to your weight). [Barding](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/equipment.html#mounts-and-related-gear) has the very same movement reduction as the table you referenced to - light barding doesn't hinder, but medium and heavy prevent fly speeds as of their own rules.

And then there are objects, like a [magic carpet](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/magicItems/wondrousItems.html#carpet-of-flying). These usually say if they work with overload and what their altered speed would be - again, it is not the armor worn by the operator, but its weight that could reduce the speed. Others like the [Crab-spider-submarine](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/magicItems/wondrousItems.html#apparatus-of-the-crab) don't state weight limits, in those cases, one might assume they operate at their top speed no manner how much is in them (but GM can also enforce a limit under Rule #0).